# What is the meaning of 踩 in 就得有一个人踩着梯子上去把球取出来?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

不过，由于栏杆上固定的是真正的筐，每当球投进时，就得有一个人踩着梯子上去把球取出来。

This is from the Standard Course Book of HSK5, section 13.

What is the meaning of 踩?

Something like:

就得有一个人踩着梯子上去 =
should exist a person stepping up to go up the ladder?

So 踩 means to step up, to walk up? To step, to walk?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"一个人踩着梯子上去", "一个人蹬着梯子上去".

I prefer the second sentence.

"踩" (cai3) and "蹬" (deng1) have similar meanings. "踩" is an action related to a foot or feet, (step on something), while "蹬" is about an action related to a leg or legs. "踩" is more about status, but "蹬" is more about force and motion.

For example, 他踩着一个硬币 (He got a coin under his foot. He stepped on a coin. He managed to hide a coin under his foot). 青蛙后腿一蹬，跳进水里。（The frog trusts its legs and jumps into the water).

Answer (score 3):

Yes.

踩 means just "having one's foot pressed on something (the ground or another object)"

Examples:

别踩着我！ Don't step on me!

他左脚踩在凳子上。 His left foot steps on the chair.

一个人踩着梯子上去。 One person goes up by stepping on a ladder.